# Adding .val() without variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the value of an input, but I can't have this:

```
$('#inputID').val();
```

Inside a seperate variable.

I have the following code:

```
var click = "$('#highlight"+n+"').replaceWith('<span id="+id+ " style="+c+">" + $("#input" + n + "").val() + "</span>');$('#black"+n+"').hide();$('#replace_box"+n+"').remove();";
```

This variable is not receiving the value of the input.

Can you explain to me why the following will not work?

```
$('#highlight"+n+"').replaceWith('<span id="+id+ " style="+c+">" + $("#input" + n + `"").val() + "</span>');`
```

And can I please get a solution. Cheers.

Comment: It's really not at all clear what you want to do here.

Comment: Your `'` and `"` don't match at all - are you sure that is the code you are actually using?

Comment: Don't put jQuery code as literal string - it's wrong and totally pointless.

Comment: If you have code in strings you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Yes Its correct code. Also this is my Unique Find/Replace System.    
You can find words on the document and then your suppose to be able to click each single word and then a box will open to replace just that one word. That's what I've been trying to do for weeks but I just can't find a solution for this! This has been so frustrating. And I was really hoping someone can finally give me the correct solution but everyone keeps on giving me useless comments(No Offence). But thanks for thanks for the help.

You can see the Find/Replace system here:  
http://yolatools.yolasite.com/find-replace.php

Comment: The comments aren't "useless" and you should pay attention to them.

Comment: This is: Don't put jQuery code as literal string - it's wrong and totally pointless. Not the part that it is wrong but the totally pointless part. Its not pointless if your in a coding situation. Where thats the only way to go.

Comment: I doubt it is the only way to go. If you'd provide more information, you might get a useful answer.

Comment: No, it's definitely not the "only way to go".  The fact that you think it is indicates even more strongly that you really should pay attention to the comments :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try some mind reading but this code won't work because you have wrong quotes:

```
$("#highlight"+n).replaceWith("<span id="+id+" style="+c+">"+$("#input" + n).val() +"</span>");
```

in any case this code would be better:

```
var span = $('<span />', {id: id, style: c});
span.html($("#input" + n).val());
$("#highlight"+n).replaceWith(span);
```

Comment: What does that second code do. Note im injecting that highlight code into an onclick using an var.

Comment: @Shawn31313 *using a variable* not "using an var" ;)